# Access an object property whose key is defined by another object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing a function (to generate an HTML table) that takes two parameters: `columns`  and `rows`.

The idea is that `rows` is an array of objects which represents the table rows, and `columns` is an object that defines which properties can be in the rows objects.

I have a type definition for `rows` which takes a generic argument of columns:

```
type column = {
  key: string;
  label: string;
};

type rows<T extends column[]> = {
  [key in T[number]["key"]]: string;
};
```

And I use these types in my table-making function:

```
interface TableBodyProps<T extends column[]> {
  columns: T;
  tableRows: rows<T>[];
}

const TableBody = <T extends column[]>({
  columns,
  tableRows,
}: TableBodyProps<T>) => {
  tableRows.forEach((row) => {
    columns.forEach((column) => {
      console.log(row[column.key]);
    });
  });
};
```

But upon trying to access `row[column.key]` I get an error:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'rows<T>'`

I guess what's happening is that `column.key` just returns a string type, so it makes sense that I couldn't use it to index. So I guess I need to tell typescript that the string I'm using is indeed a key of each row, but I *thought* that's what I was doing with the generic parameters in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use

```
type column<K> = {
  key: K;
  label: string;
};

type rows<T extends column<string>[]> = {
  [key in T[number]["key"]]: string;
};
```

so that `column["key"]` is not just `string` but a specific type (`K`). Then you can do

```
type TableBodyProps<K extends string, T extends column<K>[]> = {
  columns: column<K>[];
  tableRows: rows<T>[];
}

const TableBody = <K extends string, T extends column<K>[]>({
  columns,
  tableRows,
}: TableBodyProps<K, T>) => {
  tableRows.forEach((row) => {
    columns.forEach((column) => {
      console.log(row[column.key]);
    });
  });
};
```

<sup>([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=3&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAxg9gGwK4FsB2AeA0gPigXigG8BYAKCigGsIQAuKLAbnMoQEMAjCBBgZ2AAnAJZoA5izIBfSeVCQoguAHc+GACpQIAD2AQ0AEz6xEqTAJHicAbQC6eQqQpRrNEFFFR11tKm6DbawAiNyDbW34hUQlyGXI5cGh1LgQIACE4AxAABSUwNSwtXX0jKAtogBovIr1DY3hkdGwbewJiVhNGtD4GBrNmu0lKYBSIACUVHsVJjRbJKXiyeG7gL1GMrLbsGpLjcvEqzR1a0r6m3DscAAonSjPuio6RzlSJ1UfpBmSX9MycvIKhxwAEoCHhblBnq9JgA6ABmcEEAFF2DAABZXK5KZSg-Dgjp3UzoPjwxEo9GY+64-HOSiE7qICAwhBwMRYlTWe4wty2YFDOlSPkdQXzWRkb6pDYgG4de5TaxENwMADk7GVVQ43F4UFVyqkVUVtBVnHVUE1PGNetsH2Goze8qIupVCLgpuVJuN7EEVtiwKAA))</sup>

or just

```
type TableBodyProps<K extends string> = {
  columns: column<K>[];
  tableRows: rows<column<K>[]>[];
}

const TableBody = <K extends string>({
  columns,
  tableRows,
}: TableBodyProps<K>) => {
  tableRows.forEach((row) => {
    columns.forEach((column) => {
      console.log(row[column.key]);
    });
  });
};
```

<sup>([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAxg9gGwK4FsB2AeA0gPigXigG8BYAKCigGsIQAuKLAbnMoQEMAjCBBgZ2AAnAJZoA5izIBfSeVCQoguAHc+GACpQIAD2AQ0AEz6xEqTAJHicAbQC6eQqQpRrNEFFFR11tKm6DbawAiNyDbW34hUQlyGXI5cGh1LgQIACE4AxAABSUwNSwtXX0jKAtoh2JWE2R0PgZ4WsxcO0lKYBSIACUVesVejEazbBt7Vtj4sng0AS9OjKyCKGwivUNjcqsACidKIbqAGmqOzlSe1SPpBmTT9MycvIKcAEoCPF2oE7PegDoAMzgggAouwYAALLZbJTKV74d7VPamOr-QEg8GQ-ZoWHw5yUREzRAQH4IOBiKEqayYn5uWzPNp4qR06qMyRxMjkG6pBYgHbVTF9axENwMADk7BFBygHG4vCgYpFUklQtoos4EqlXB4qoVtku7U65wFRHlooBcHVIrVqvYgh1sWeQA))</sup>

where `rows<column<K>[]>` is just `Record<K, string>`. The separate `T` parameter is only useful if you want to do something else with the specific cell type, e.g. pass it to a callback that takes a concrete `T`.

Comment: When I define `columns` and `tableRows` directly in the `TableBody` function call, the arguments are successfully typechecked. But if I define them beforehand in their own named variables, and _then_ pass them into `TableBody`, the table keys aren't checked. Any idea why? (Sorry I can't figure out how to share a TS playground link, since shortened URLs aren't allowed)

Comment: You might need to use `as const` for the precise type to be assigned instead of having it widened (probably to `string`).

Comment: (Don't share a *shortened* playground link, just share the link itself - it should fit well within the comment size limit, or you're sharing too much code)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a second type parameter to `TableBodyProps` that is constrained to the first, that way you can say that all column keys must be one of the table row properties

```
type column<K extends string> = {
  key: K;
  label: string;
};

type rows<K extends string> = {
  [P in K]: string;
};

type TableBodyProps<K extends string, L extends K> = {
  columns: column<L>[];
  tableRows: rows<K>[];
}

const TableBody = <K extends string, L extends K>({
  columns,
  tableRows,
}: TableBodyProps<K, L>) => {
  tableRows.forEach((row) => {
    columns.forEach((column) => {
      console.log(row[column.key]);
    });
  });
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAxg9gGwK4FsB2AeA0lCAPYCNAEwGcpTgAnASzQHMA%20KAXigG8BYAKCigGsIIAFxQsAbh58EAQwBGEBKMq0Gk7gF91PUJChU4Ad1LZcBImQrU6TVhylQA2gAUodMQF1l1tTy08dcGgAFXkECAAhOGIQZwMwExx8QhJyFRsAGigAGTMUyyxmNi5eWERUNFJReGR0DGzGRw91PmAwiAAlIyr9buxG5r8A7nhK4ChQuXComLtTZIs0n3os3IXUsUYAChK%20GorSDIc2qc7uo81RSeno2PjE1cYASlZmXagT8K7jADoAMzgVAAojIYAALLZbAyGF4sN4OPbldCkf6AkHgyH7dCw%20GlPiIyqICA-BBwehQoyOLFoH6CEAeJ4tfEaRkOFnqfzcHjXSK3HYOak9RzsOmiADkMjFWVkCiUUAlYo0WRFQnFcilUBlijVio8F1a7W%20QvYCvFALgGrF6rVMiour8TyAA)